# sql query if where condition of one tble z true then fetch related data frm next table as well as same table in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

i had created two table `products` and `bid`. in `products` table there is a column `verified`. both table contain `product_id`. i need to write an sql query in `zend frameWork` for fetching data from `products` table , where verified column value is `Yes` and also the related data from `bid` table using foreign key `product_id`. 
I tried with the below query. But its fetching first one data only, whose `product_id` is available in both `bid` and `product` table.

sql query

```
public function fetchAllProductItems() {
    $oSelect = $this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from(array("p" => "products","b" => "bid"), ('*'))
            ->join(array("b" => "bid"), "b.product_id=p.product_id", array('bid_id','bid_amount'))
            ->where("p.verified = ?", "Yes");

    return $oSelect;


}
```

Please anyone help me to write the exact query. 
Replies are appreciable